# Convert CachedOutputStream to a string

Tags: apache-camel

Convert CachedOutputStream to a string.
After upgrading camel from 2.12 to 2.23 I have a problem on my route, same code same route.

The response after calling a endpoint is of type  `org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream`
I tried to convert the `CachedOutputStream` to a String.

```
String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
logger.info("FJA the string after caling endpoint: " + body);
```

I dk.bankconnect.hub.Util efter FJA efter  streng er:

> -0��phjA����/h`�FhI[����G<�����,�Z���f���=��Rϝ��s#���O��~#�G�t

How to convert the CachedOutputStream to a string?

I tried many different things to avoid the response to come as a stream. However, I do not succeeded.

Here is a little snippet of my route:

```
from("direct:sdc:webservice")
            .setProperty("webservice", constant(Boolean.TRUE))    
            .setProperty("duration", simple("Forwarding request to ${property.datacentral} datacentral"))
            .choice().when().simple("${property.Tracked} == true").bean(Util.class, "dura-tion").end()
            .bean(Util.class, "tracker")
            .bean(Util.class, "foer")
            .to(Util.getProperty("sdc.url"))
            .bean(Util.class, "efter")
            .convertBodyTo(Document.class)            
            .setProperty("duration", simple("Receiving response from ${proper-ty.datacentral} datacentral"))
            .choice().when().simple("${property.Tracked} == true").bean(Util.class, "dura-tion").end()
            .bean(Util.class, "tracker")
            .setProperty(SoapError.FAULT, xpath("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Fault/faultstring/text()", String.class).namespace("soapenv", Namespace.SOAP))
            .end();
```

My convertBodyTo fails, because its suddenly a stream.

Comment: I suggest to spend a little bit more time to format this questions so its readable - you have then a higher chance for ppl want/can help you

Comment: I found out what was wrong:From Camel 2.3: when bridgeEndpoint true the HttpProducer and CamelServlet will skip gzip processing when content-encoding=gzip. Why skip this ? i have solved it by checking the header if its gzip and encoded it like this :   .choice().when().method(Util.class, "isGzip").unmarshal().gzip()

Comment: .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")  works for me, body in my case is response from a http call

Answer (score 0):

Ok, very short

The response after calling a endpoint is of type org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream
I tried to convert the CachedOutputStream to a String.

String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

This is not a String that is readable, but many special characters.

Frank :-)

Comment: Where is your CachedOutputStream?